# How to send the data to API to update an object, when controller is holding an Observable (Angular 6)

Tags: angular, observable, reactive-programming

I am working with Angular 6 to build couple of simple things and now hitting a wall with Observables.

I have a component that fetched a project onInit:

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.project$ = this.route.paramMap.pipe(
      switchMap((params: ParamMap) => this.projectService.getProjectById(+params.get('id')))
    );
  }
```

As you can see `this.project$` is Observable, and I am using it in the template as `async`:

```
<div *ngIf="project$ | async as project">
...
</div>
```

All good for now...

As part of this component I need to allow user to update some details of the project, and I am using reactive form for it and in particular the title:

```
saveTitle() {
    if (this.projectTitleFormGroup.invalid) {
      return;
    }

    let projectToUpdate = ???

    this.projectService.updateProject(projectToUpdate)
  }
```

Since the controller holds an Observable, how do I operate with it if my project service expects a Project instance?

I mean, of course, instead of holding an Observable I could subscribe to the `getProject` function and get the actual project object instance.
My question is, is this the only way to do it, or there are some other practices to do the same with Observables?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

You can get the edited project instance in your save method with

```
// let projectToUpdate = ???
const projectToUpdate = this.projectTitleFormGroup.getRawValue();
```

This solution, while working, might not be the best one, as you are modifying the 'transient' project instance which is provided by the async pipe over which you do not really have any control.

You could also implement a [ControlValueAccessor](https://angular.io/api/forms/ControlValueAccessor) for your project form component, which supports `ngModel` for a whole `project` instance. Then all changes to that form will be propagated using the full `project` instance.

The problem you are encountering is tightly related to state management and there is a great library called [ngrx](https://github.com/ngrx) which helps in situations like yours.
It is definitely worth checking it out.

Comment: I don't think that passing the object into save function is going to work, as at that point, the object did not really change yet, the form did. Unless you are suggesting to treat this one as `before` the update.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by the first option => `ERROR in src/app/project/project-details/project-details.component.ts(47,60): error TS2339: Property 'withLatestFrom' does not exist on type 'Observable<any>'.` Do I need some addition library for it?

Comment: You are right, I did not realize, that you obviously need the edited instance and not the original one in your save function. I removed those suggestions from my answer, please check the updated one.

Answer (score 0):

How i usually do it:

```
project$: BehaviorSubject<any> = new BehaviorSubject<any>(null);

ngOnInit() {
    this.route.paramMap.pipe(
      switchMap((params: ParamMap) => this.projectService.getProjectById(+params.get('id')))
    ).subscribe(project => this.project$.next(project));
}

saveTitle() {
    if (this.projectTitleFormGroup.invalid) {
      return;
    }

    let projectToUpdate = ???

    this.projectService.updateProject(projectToUpdate).subscribe(updatedProject => this.project$.next(updatedProject))
}
```

There are other approaches, but in my opinion this is the most simple approach, and simplicity does it for me ;)

If your updateProject method does not return an updatedProject, just add a switchMap to retrieve it again ...

Dont forget to clean up those subscriptions though:
https://alligator.io/angular/takeuntil-rxjs-unsubscribe/

Comment: What is the point to use `BehaviorSubject` here is you subscribe to the initial Observable anyways and you can simply operate on the project object instance itself?

Comment: The idea is that in your screen, you will subscribe to this subject. If you need to update the data, you simply call the .next() method. (what the call to updateProject in the saveTitle method). Maybe i didnt fully understood your question?